# YouTube iFrame hide info

Tags: ios, youtube-api

I know about `showinfo` parameter of YouTube API. But it doesn't match my requirement. After finish playback, the video info will be shown again. Is there anyway to completely hide video info?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using the [youtube-ios-player-helper](https://github.com/youtube/youtube-ios-player-helper), you can implement the delegate method:

```
- (void)playerView:(YTPlayerView *)ytPlayerView didChangeToState:(YTPlayerState)state
```

and check for `kYTPlayerStateEnded`.  When the video ends, the callback will fire indicating that the video has ended.  You can then do whatever you requirement is, completely hide the player or the `YTPlayerView`, load a different view, etc,

Answer (score 0):

Try this with the playerVars parameter combination

```
NSDictionary *playerVars = @{
                             @"controls" : @0,
                             @"playsinline" : @1,
                             @"autohide" : @1,
                             @"showinfo" : @0,
                             @"modestbranding" : @1,
                             @"rel":@0
                             };
```